# Как рассчитать количество времени до определенной даты

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать таймер в Python. Он должен работать примерно так: я програмирую определенную дату( например новый год), а человек, который заходит, видит количество дней, часов, минут до этой даты

Answer (score 1):

1. получите время даты 1 в секундах
2. получите время даты 2 в секундах
3. получите разницу между датам в секундах - `delta`
4. `delta % 60` - секунды
5. `(delta % 3600) // 60` - минуты
   ну и т.д.

хотя это я усложняю даже, есть же библиотеки:

```
import datetime

delta = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1) - datetime.datetime.now()

print(delta.days, delta.seconds // 3600, (delta.seconds // 60) % 60, delta.seconds % 60)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как дать ему узнать время сегодняшней даты?

Comment: посмотрите я код добавил - можно сделать еще проще